# Yosemite gray screen no startup keys working

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I restarted my macbook pro this morning and it started up with a chime and now is stuck on the grey screen. I have tries holding any different key combinations, none of them work, except resetting the pram, which does cause the computer to restart.

I have tried option, r, s, d, command shift v, command v, shift (before and after the chime), command option d r.

FYI I have been running yosemitr for a while with no problems. I shut my computer last night and it was working fine. This happened when I turned it on today.

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Year purchased your computer, specs, etc? Have you just installed Yosemite and this is the first time booting, or have you been running OS X 10.10 for a while now? How long was your laptop on since you last restarted - I ask because Apple just released the 10.10.1 update and I wonder if it's failing to complete that update...

Comment: OK added some context details. I'm unsure if it got the latest update, but I think so like a weak ago.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect everything from the Mac and then power it off.

Perform recovery according to these steps.

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718

If that fails, then you may need support from Apple to determine the version of OS X that shipped with the Mac so you can restore that and start over/restore from a backup once the hardware is known to work. Or it needs a repair for hardware issues.

Comment: I am gonna bring it to an apple store tomorrow. Command r has no effect when starting up.

Comment: @saul.shanabrook Good plan - when the system can't even boot to internet recovery, something hardware is usually involved.

Answer (score 1):

I press <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>⎋esc</kbd>, and then the login screen appears. It's always after an update that this happens. It has usually righted itself eventually.